# How does this dynamic object creation look like in terms of correctness or good code structure?

Tags: c++, c++14, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is a part of code for A* algorithm. I want to know if this is good, or I'd be better off using static allocation of memory here (I think that would be better). But not very sure as new to C++. Also, I'm using grid for the algorithm so how do I delete this. Please guide. Any suggestions welcome. Thanks.

```
for (int i = 0; i<world.size()-1 ; i++)
{
     for(int j =0; j<world[0].size()-1; j++)
     {           
         Node* a = new Node(make_pair(i,j), world[i][j]);
         grid[i].push_back(*a);
     }
}
```

Comment: Memory leak galore.

Comment: Consider that whenever you explicitly use `new` there is probably something wrong with your code.

Comment: There is no point using dynamic allocation if you are going to copy its value and throw away the pointer.

Comment: This might be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) but it is definitely off-topic here.

Comment: Yes, I realize now that dynamic allocation is useful when unsure of the size or going to add more things to the heap.  So, I should use :                    Node a(make_pair(i,j), world[i][j]); grid[i].push_back(a);

Comment: Dynamic is also useful for objects with no fixed lifetime. That said, you almost always want to tie the lifetime to something. [Read up on RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii) and the concept of ownership.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are pushing `Node` instead of `Node*` to the `grid` vector, you are copying value of `*a` (by copy/move constructor). Therefore the allocated `Node` will only be used for copying, and then never used.

You should either use local variable, and then you dont care for any deletion from your side

```
Node a = Node(make_pair(i,j), world[i][j]);
grid[i].push_back(a);
```

Or you can make grid a vector of pointers (`vector<Node*>`) and push the `a` itself. Then you have to manualy delete all pointers in vector the same way you did create them.

```
Node* a = new Node(make_pair(i,j), world[i][j]);
grid[i].push_back(a);
```

First case can be made better with `emplace` function, avoiding copying - constructing `Node` in the array of vector:

```
grid[i].emplace_back(make_pair(i,j), world[i][j]);
```

In second case, you could use some smart pointers, for example std::unique_ptr (vector>), so that you dont have to manually delete the pointers. Destructor of unique_pointer will handle it.

```
grid[i].push_back(make_unique<Node>(make_pair(i,j), world[i][j]));
```

Answer (score -1):

A tip would be to store the address rather then object. A map would be a useful object to manage you nodes.